# Is it possible to hide BigQuery query execution logs in Google Cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

Based on my understanding Google Cloud platform does not provide Bigquery specific Logging api that we can disable so that BQ sql query does not get logged.

Any reference or workaround will be highly appriciated.

Use case:
Queries need to be executed in client dataset and data has to stay within client project only.

Comment: I didn't get If query is executed in client dataset and (assumingly) in client project, who wants to hide the query? the client? why would they if query is in their own project?

Answer (score 1):

There is no data in the Logs, only the query performed. However, you [can exclude the logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions) if you want. but you won't be able to track, debug, understand what happened. If you are safe with this, so, go ahead!